# Passing value of subquery in query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to use the result of a subquery to be passed in the general query, but instead the value of the subquery is directly returned.
In the below example, I have a table containing some numeric *results*, and a second table containing the *formulas* to be used in the query.

I have no problem querying the results directly by hardcoding the formulas:

```
SELECT      (col1 + col2)   AS "Result1", 
            col2            AS "Result2",                      
FROM   
myschema.results
```

But I'd like to use a subquery to fetch the formula from the formula table:

```
SELECT      (SELECT formula FROM myschema.formulas WHERE id = 'res1')    AS "Result1", 
            col2            AS "Result2",                      
FROM   
myschema.results
```

In the first query I correctly get something like

```
Result 1    Result 2
3           2
```

But when using the subquery I incorrectly get:

```
Result 1    Result 2
col1 + col2         2
```

How can I makesure the subquery result gets interpreted in the first query? I found some solutions using joins, but I'm not sure this is what I need and wonder if there is a simpler way to achieve this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: please update your questions with solution using join you have found.

Comment: You'll need something like this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/store-a-formula-in-a-table-and-use-the-formula-in-a-function

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is dynamic SQL.

Something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS SETOF int AS
$$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || (SELECT 'x'::text) ||' FROM generate_series(1,10) AS gs(x);';
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```